# JavaScript nested namespace generation code explanation needed

Tags: javascript, namespaces, design-patterns

can anyone explain how this below works?

```
var MYAPP = {};
MYAPP.namespace = function(name){
    var parts = name.split('.');
    var current = MYAPP;
    for (var i in parts) {
        if (!current[parts[i]]) {
            current[parts[i]] = {};
        }
        // shouldn't this line override the MYAPP object with all it's properties?
        current = current[parts[i]];
    }
}
```

Comment: that line _overwrites_ the **pointer** `current` that points to `MYAPP`. It doesn't overwrite the **value** `MYAPP`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`current` is first assigned a *reference* to `MYAPP`, after that, within the loop, for every part of the Array from `name.split` it is subsequently assigned a reference to the freshly made property of `MYAPP`. So nothing is overwritten, because it's all *references*.

in words for example if you execute `MYAPP.namespace(foo.bar)` this happens:

- first: `current` points to `MYAPP`
- now go into the loop. If `current /*is ref to MYAPP*/ .foo` doesn't exist, create `MYAPP.foo`
- let `current` point to `MYAPP.foo`
- if `current /*is now ref to MYAPP.foo*/ .bar` doesn't exist create it
- finally `MYAPP` contains:

  - `MYAPP.foo`
  - `MYAPP.foo.bar`
- If you wanted to assign the same to `MYAPP` as `MYAPP.namespace(foo.bar)` using an object literal, you would write

  - `var MYAPP = { foo: { bar: {} }`

Comment: thanks, the problem was that reassignment from "MYAPP.foo to MYAPP.foo.bar" confused me, great explanation, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

All this does really is initializing empty objects.

When you call `MYAPP.namespace('foo.bar')` it will create an empty object (`{}`) in `MYAPP.foo` and then again one in `MYAPP.foo.bar`. That way you can then add functions and variables into `MYAPP.foo.bar`.

Answer (score 0):

The `namespace` method lets you create nested objects in the `MYAPP` object.

If you call `MYAPP.namespace('foo.bar')` it will:

- check if `MYAPP.foo` exists, and create it if it doesn't.
- check if `MYAPP.foo.bar` exists, and create it if it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I will explain it with the code sample.
See this code `var MYAPP = {}` creates a global empty object if left like now.
`MYAPP.namespace` is a instance method for the object and can be used like `MYAPP.namespace("foo.bar")`

lets get into quick preview,
when i do this `MYAPP.namespace("ice.cream")`
it creates two inner objects by checking previous existence like `MYAPP.ice.Cream` which act individually
And Yes that line does override our initial MYAPP object, remove that line or abstract away the namespace method to global utils. something like `Utils.registerNameSpace("MYAPP.Ice.Cream");`